# Input value checked as unique and then added to Object Array - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object

So I'm trying to design a form that will have 3 input fields (Cust ID, Cust Name and Amount), the ID would need to be checked if it exists in the Object Array, and if so throw an error, otherwise it would add all 3 values to the Object Array.

I need to use an object so that I don't use a multitude of Arrays, however I've never actually used an Object based Array, so if anyone is able to provide an example of how to use it that would be a massive help!

```
var garrCust = {id:"", name:"", amount:""};


function addCust(){
    var custID = document.getElementById("custid").value;
    var custName = document.getElementById("custname").value;
    var amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;

    if(!custID){
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "ID Cannot be Blank";
        return false;}


    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "<br />Added " + custID + "<br /><br />";
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "List contains: " + garrCust.id;
    return true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use an ID to name-and-amount object map to simplify and speed-up the lookup:

```
var garrCust = []; // an array of id -> {id:"", name:"", amount:""}

function addCust(){
    var custID = document.getElementById("custid").value;
    var custName = document.getElementById("custname").value;
    var amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;

    if(!custID){
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "ID Cannot be Blank";
        return false;
    }

    if (!garrCust[custID]) {
        // ID not found in the array
        garrCust[custID] = { id: custID, name : custName, 'amount' : amount};
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "<br />Added " + custID + "<br /><br />";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "List contains: " + garrCust.id;
    }

    return true;
}
```

NOTE: Storing ID as part of object is actually optional as it is already associated with an entry as an array index

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for that!

I just gave it a go, however when trying to display what's in the array, it doesn't seem to work?

    function listCust(){
     document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "<br />List contains: " + garrCust.id + garrCust.name + garrCust.amount;

    }

Comment: Remember, our associative array has IDs as keys, so an individual entriy should be addressed as garrCust[id].name + '  ' + garrCust[id].amount. 

An easy way to print the entire array, though, is this:

 listCust(){ document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "<br />List contains: " + JSON.stringify(garrCust); }

Comment: If you want to *iterate* through entries of this array for whatever reason, you'd go like this:

for (var id in garrCust) {
   // do something with garrCust[id]:
   console.log(id + ' ' + garrCust[id].name + ' ' + garrCust[id].amount);
}

Answer (score 0):

You may also use a constructor to define the object content and the id as the property to index them like so:

```
// Create an object with the two properties name and amount
function Customer(name,amount) {
    this.name = name;
    this.amount = amount;
}

// Declare some variables
var id, c;
var customers = {};

// Sample names
var name = [ 'one','two','three','four','five' ];

// Create five sample entries - reusing id for amount
for (id = 0; id < 5; id++) {
    // Using the new keyword with customer creates the object with 
    // the data you pass
    customers[id] = new Customer(name[id],id);
}

// A loop to test for the presence of customer ids
for (c = 0; c < 5; c++) {
    id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
    if (customers.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
        console.log(id+" exists");
    } else {
        console.log(id+" does not exist");
    }
}
```

This would create an object that had objects as properties, and the name of the properties is the customer id.

> customers = { 44: { name: "John", amount: 6 },
>                33: { name: "Sally", amount: 5}};

To display the customer list, you may use the following:

```
var html;
// Use a template literal to build the list item for each customer
function listTemplate(id,name,amount) {
        return `<li><span class="id">${id}</span>
                <span class="name">${name}</span>
                <span class="amount">${amount}</span></li>`;
}
html = "<ul>";

// Iterate through all the customers
for (id in customers) {
        c = customers[id];
        // Concatenate the list items
        html += listTemplate(id,c.name,c.amount);
}
html += "</ul>";

// Add the HTML into the DOM
document.getElementById("customer-list").innerHTML = html;
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for this.

If I wanted to say print out each entry, how could I go about that?

I would need to print it out like:

Customer ID: <id>  Customer Name: <name>  Amount: <amount>